# Do while run but not actually running?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Hi i'm a college student and i tried to convert my program from if to do while in arduino but It just seem to doesn't work. this is my original if program

```
  if (pot < 200)
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  if (pot > 200) 
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  if (pot > 300)
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  if (pot > 400)
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  if (pot > 500)
```

converted to

```
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  }while (pot < 200);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 200); 
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 300);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 400);
  do{
```

and i still can't figured out what's wrong with my code any help would be appreciated.

edit 1

```
const int eLDeeR = A0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for(int i=5; i<=12; i++) { 
  pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
   int pot = analogRead(eLDeeR);
   // Do a little animation by writing to the same location
   for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
      for ( int j = 0; j < 1; j++ )
   delay (200);
  Serial.println(pot);
  for(int i=5 ; i<=12; i++){
    digitalWrite(i,LOW);
    }
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  }while (pot < 200);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 200); 
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 300);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 400);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  }while(pot > 500);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 600);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 700);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
  }while(pot > 800);
  do{ 
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  }while (pot > 900);

}
```

Comment: In the second example, you set `pot` once somewhere, but then you enter an infinite loop without ever updating the value.  You also change the pin before testing the condition... seems backwards. Maybe a plain `while cond {set pin}` is better?   I see no problem with the first example... it looks like you're making a little bar graph meter...maybe you want to reset pins 10 and 11 when you set/reset pin 12???

Comment: Horrible code.  Why put a a `do` loop inside the `loop` loop?  Terrible idea.  You need to read the datasheet for your part and follow Atmel/Microchip code examples.  And more to the point, what "doesn't work" about it?  Answer that and write it down.  Your code is not testable as posted, what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The if-statements are fine. Your attempt to change the code into do-while statements will likely result in an infinite loop that will hang your program. My tips:

1:
The code fragments you posted are incomplete, as posted they cannot work. Are they in a loop? They should be inside a loop, like the main loop.

2: Inside the loop the variable 'pot' must be updated inside the loop or the result of the conditions will forever stay the same.

3: You probably want to pull pins 11 and 10 to LOW when pot is smaller than 300. And  pull pin 11 to LOW when pot is smaller than 400. But you will have to add explicit statements to do that. The pins will not revert back to LOW automatically.

4: Use indenting. It will make your code more readable and much easier to troubleshoot.

So try something like:

```
void loop() {
  
  [update pot variable here] 
  
  if (pot > 200)
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  else
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  if (pot > 300)
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  else
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);    
  if (pot > 400)
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  else
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
}
```

Comment: hmm my code might actually be in a loop but I'm still scratching my head with the do while function because my assignment is in do while form. I'll try what you suggested thanks for replying. p.s i edited the post I posted the whole program below the do while.